# Utility to find join columns

Tags: python, sql, r, sql-server

I have been given several tables in SQL Server and am trying to figure out the best way to join them.

What I've done is:

```
1) open a connection in R to the database
2) pull all the column names from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table
3) build loops in R to try every combination of columns and see what the row count is of the inner join of the 2 columns
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this or if there's a package or utility that helps with this type of problem.

Comment: So the problem is, you have a database nobody knows the meaning of the objects of? Or is this an academic problem or just for fun?

Comment: Did you try using sql join?

Comment: If you're lucky, the columns that relate entities together will be described in the foreign key constraints.

Comment: @stickybit: the issue is that the tables come from flat files that come from different parts of a large organization that doesn't have uniform data governance.  One department uses 'SKU' while another uses 'ResourceID' for the same data.

Comment: Then someone should bring that parts together and create a global schema. Of course you can test around with more or less all combinations of columns and tables, but you'll never know if a "hit" is just coincidental. Say for example you got a log of users and about the same number of products and all have numerical IDs in the same range. Joining the users and the products will likely result in a large but actually meaningless set. The "results" you get from this approach seem very fragile.

Answer (score -1):

You could do your joins in python using pandas. Pandas has a powerful IO engine, so you could import from SQL Server into a pandas dataframe, perform your joins with python and write back to SQL server.

Below is a script I use to perform an import from SQL Server and an export to a MySQL table. I use the python package sqlalchemy for my ORM connections. You could follow this example and read up on joins in pandas.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# MySQL info
username = 'user'
password = 'pw'
sqlDB = 'mydb'

# Create MSSQL PSS Connector
server = 'server'
database = 'mydb'
connMSSQL = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' +
    f'SERVER={server};PORT=1433;DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=yes;')

# Read Table into pandas dataframe
tsql = '''
SELECT  [Index],
        Tag,
FROM [dbo].[Tags]
'''
df = pd.read_sql(tsql, connMSSQL, index_col='Index')

# Write df to MySQL db
engine = create_engine(
    f'mysql+mysqldb://{username}:{password}@localhost/mydb', pool_recycle=3600)
with engine.connect() as connMySQL:
    df.to_sql('pss_alarms', connMySQL, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Could you provide reasons why doing joins in Pandas is preferable to doing joins in SQL? I'm not sure I see how this addresses OP's problem of not knowing which columns to join...